# Notifications not popping up on selected days of week

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

i am working on an alarm app in which user can select days of week on which he wants to ring the alarm. In my code if I'm executing the condition for "same day" only then alarm is ringing on every day. But when I'm selecting the other two conditions i.e. "Next day" and "Previous day", notifications are not firing. Although the notifications are created but they are not firing. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code

```
func scheduleUserNotifications(for alarm: Alarm)
    {
        let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        notificationContent.title = "HelloK"
        if alarm.name.isEmpty == false
        {
            notificationContent.body = "Please respond to your alarm \(alarm.name)"
        }
        else
        {
            alarm.name = "Empty" 
        }
        let song = AlarmController.shared.tone
        print (song)
        notificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: song)
        print(notificationContent.sound)
        print(AlarmController.shared.counter)
        var countNum: Int!
        if AlarmController.shared.counter == "30 Minutes"
        {
            countNum = 6
        }
        else if AlarmController.shared.counter == "1 Hour"
        {
            countNum = 12
        }
        else
        {
            countNum = 36
        }

        print(countNum)

        var daysValue: [Int]
        daysValue = AlarmController.shared.days

        print(daysValue)
        var dateVal = 0
        for day in daysValue
        {
            print(dateVal)
            if day == 1
            {
                print("hello")

                guard let fireDate = alarm.fireDate else { return }
                print(fireDate)

                let dateToChange = fireDate
                var nextDate = dateToChange
                var difference : Int?
//                var addComponent : Calendar.Component?
                let weekday = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: fireDate)
                print(weekday)

                if dateVal == weekday-1
                {
                    print("same day")
                    nextDate = fireDate
//                  nextDate = fireDate.addingTimeInterval(7*86400)
                    print(nextDate)
                }
                else if dateVal > weekday-1
                {
                    print("next day")
                    difference = dateVal - (weekday-1)
                    print(difference!)
                    nextDate = fireDate.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(difference!*86400))
                    print(nextDate)
                }
                else if dateVal < weekday-1
                {
                    print("previous day")
                    difference = 7-(weekday-1)+dateVal
                    print(difference!)
                    nextDate = fireDate.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(difference!*86400))
                    print(nextDate)
                }

                for ind in 0...countNum
                {
                    let date = nextDate.addingTimeInterval((1.0*Double(ind)) * 60.0)
                    print(date)

                    let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                            print(triggerDate)
                            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: true)
                            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "\(alarm.uuid)\(ind)", content: notificationContent, trigger: trigger)
//                            print(request)
                            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
                            {
                                (error) in
                                if let error = error
                                {
                                    print("Unable to add notification request, \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                }
                            }

                        }
                }

            }

            dateVal += 1
        }
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.getPendingNotificationRequests { (notifications) in
            print("Count: \(notifications.count)")
            for item in notifications {
                print(item.content)
            }
        }

    }
```

when I remove this part of my code, notifications are working fine but they are firing on every day

```
else if dateVal > weekday-1
                {
                    print("next day")
                    difference = dateVal - (weekday-1)
                    print(difference!)
                    nextDate = fireDate.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(difference!*86400))
                    print(nextDate)
                }
                else if dateVal < weekday-1
                {
                    print("previous day")
                    difference = 7-(weekday-1)+dateVal
                    print(difference!)
                    nextDate = fireDate.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(difference!*86400))
                    print(nextDate)
                }
```

but when i uncomment it, no notification appears